# How to split this into two lines

Tags: math-mode, fractions

This is my code:

```
\begin{equation}
\text{Diluted EPS}=\frac{\text{Net Income}}{\text{Weighted average number of shares outstanding + New common shares that would have been issued at conversion}}
\end{equation}
```

Looks like this... horrible:

[image]

Comment: How would you do this by hand?  The first thought that occurs to me is `$=\frac{N}{W+C}$, where $N$ is ...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an alternative you could add some line breaks. One way to achieve this is using `\substack`. This will typically reduce the font size, which is usually appropriate, but it can be changed back to normal using `\normalfontsize`. Similarly, adding in parentheses, while not always required, should always be considered. As an example output:

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{Diluted EPS}=\dfrac{\text{Net
Income}}{\substack{\text{Weighted average number}\\ \text{of shares
outstanding}}+ \substack{\text{New common shares that}\\ \text{would have been}\\ \text{issued
at conversion}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution !

Comment: Thanks, this is the cleanest solution thus marking as correct

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE...

Try with `\splitfrac` from `mathtools.sty`, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{Diluted EPS}=\frac{\text{Net
Income}}{\splitdfrac{\text{Weighted average number of shares
outstanding}}{+ \text{New common shares that would have been issued
at conversion}}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```